# Discord.JS, Displaying multiple user Profile Pictures in For Loop using Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, discord, discord.js

I am creating a user leaderboard using Canvas, and all stats are working fine. One thing I'm having trouble with is displaying the profile picture for each user on the leaderboard. The last place user's pfp shows up, and I am assuming the rest are beneath it, but I am having trouble getting each pfp on a new line. Any help's appreciated. Thank you!

Code:

```
  for (var i in level) {
   
  let user = await client.users.fetch(`${level[i].ID.replace('guild_646074330249429012_level_', '')}`).catch(console.error);


    numList += `${level.indexOf(level[i])+1}.\n\n`
    
    usernames +=  `${user.username}- Level ${level[i].data}\n\n` 
    
  ctx.font = "15px coolvetica_rg";
  ctx.textAlign - "center";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
  ctx.fillText(numList, 22, 80);

  ctx.font = "24px coolvetica_rg";
  ctx.textAlign - "center";
  ctx.fillStyle =  "#FFFFFF";
  ctx.fillText(usernames, 50, 80);
  ctx.width = "30px";
  ctx.length = "200px";
  ctx.margin = "30px";

  const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg' }));
  ctx.drawImage(avatar, 10, 10, 50, 50); 
  }
```

Result: Only one user's profile picture shows up (User in last leaderboard spot)

Comment: It looks like you're drawing the image on the same location each time.  You'll need to draw it at dimensions that change based on how many users there are on a background that fits that amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the avatars are drawn on the canvas, the only reason you can only see the last one is because you drew them in the same position on top of each other.

You already have a variable (`i`) that increases after every iteration. You should use this to increase the Y coordinate of the images, something like this:

```js
let size = 50
let padding = 10
ctx.drawImage(avatar, padding, padding + i * (size + padding), size, size);
```

The [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) method's second and third parameters are the X and Y coordinates of the image.

Comment: Oh man, It for some reason didn't pass my mind that I could use the i var, your solution did the trick, thank you so much!!